# Laravel 5. Translate errors from forms

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel-5, translate

I want to translate form errors to other language.

I created language folder: resources/lang/lt and insinde validation.php file with translated text.

In template show errors like this:

```
                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
```

But every time I get errors from resources/lang/en/validation.php file, maybe I have somehow use trans function insinde errors loop?

For translation I use mcamara/laravel-localization package. Everything works except errors.

Comment: Have you actually changed the locale in `config/app.php`?

Comment: It's default value 'en', but it's okay, bucause I want two languages and english is default

Comment: Yes but the error messages will show up in the language the `locale` value is set to. Or are you setting it dynamically somewhere (because you need to do that if you have a multilingual site)

Comment: I use mcamara/laravel-localization package and with it locale changes by route like this en/home or lt/home

Comment: Well I don't know the package... Try to output the locale in the view to make sure it's set correctly `{{ config('app.locale') }}`

Comment: Yes, it's set correctly

Comment: Hmm. Then I don't really know what the problem is... In general the error messages should be translated automatically.